# High and Tight Meaning

Tags: idioms, slang

This is a quote from the movie Avatar:
"Col. Quaritch: I want this mission high and tight. I wanna be home for dinner."

I seem to remember hearing "high and tight" used elsewhere. But I couldn't pin down its exact meaning. Is this a common slang or idiom, and if so, what is its meaning? Please provide references if possible.

Comment: If you are from the United States, you may have heard "high and tight" used as a description of a pitch in baseball that comes in just under the batter's chin (without hitting him). Another term for this particular pitch location is "up and in." But I don't think that the _Avatar_ usage has anything to do with the U.S. baseball usage.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience as a US Marine, it was only used to refer to haircuts. It's a movie. Avatar, no less. And that dude ain't no REAL Marine. After 20 years out of the service, I could be wrong, but in that movie, the writer just didn't freakin know he was using the term wrong, and no one wants to tell Jamers Cameron he's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that it refers to a popular haircut style found in military and police forces.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_and_tight

As a metaphor, it probably means the mission is to be carried out neatly, quickly, no fuss and no complications.

Comment: [Routledge Dictionary of Modern American Slang and Unconventional English](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=neVBmSyNRnEC&lpg=PA502&ots=zAYzEzmLLP&dq=slang%20%22high%20and%20tight%22&pg=PA502#v=onepage&q=slang%20%22high%20and%20tight%22&f=false) supports this.

Comment: Thanks - I have found quite a few sources with the haircut explanation, but none with the idiomatic or metaphorical meaning. This leads me to think it is not in fact an accepted idiom in widespread usage. This is a bit off-topic, but would you two have any suggestions for similar idioms (with the metaphorical meaning mentioned by Joe Dark above)?